# Prove that a sequence is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of iid random variables. Let $\{Y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of random variables such that $$Y_{n+1}=f(Y_n,X_n) \quad\forall\, n \in \mathbb{N}$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a deterministic function.
Prove that $\{Y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov chain.

This is what I've done so far:

$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=k\mid Y_n=j)$ we know that $Y_{n+1}=f(Y_n,X_n)=f(j,X_n)$  and that's where I got stuck.

Comment: Are $Y_n$ assumed discrete in the problem?

Comment: It's not specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P\big(&Y_{n+1}\in A\,\big|\,Y_n=y_n,Y_{n-1}=y_{n-1},\dots, Y_0=y_0\big)\\
=P\big(&f\big(Y_n,X_n\big)\in A\,\big|\,Y_n=y_n,Y_{n-1}=y_{n-1},\dots, Y_0=y_0\big)\\
=P\big(&f\big(y_n,X_n\big)\in A\,\big|\,Y_n=y_n,Y_{n-1}=y_{n-1},\dots, Y_0=y_0\big)\\
=P\big(&\big(y_n,X_n\big)\in f^{-1}(A)\,\big|\,Y_n=y_n,Y_{n-1}=y_{n-1},\dots, Y_0=y_0 \big)\\
=P\big(&\big(y_n,X_n\big)\in f^{-1}(A)\,\big)\ \ \ \ \text{ by independence}\\
=P\big(&\big(Y_n,X_n\big)\in f^{-1}(A)\,\big|\,Y_n=y_n\big)\\
=P\big(&Y_{n+1}\in A\,\big|\,Y_n=y_n\ \big)\ .
\end{align}
The identity of the first and last expressions in this chain of identities is precisely the condition required for $\ \big\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ to be a Markov chain.

Comment: What are you assuming as A?

Comment: The equation has to hold (as it does, in fact, do)  for $\ A\ $ being any measurable subset of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $.

Comment: For merely deterministic $f$ such that $f(Y_n,X_n)$ is a random variable (which seems to be the only restriction on $f$), is there a reason to assume $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable?

Comment: I was assuming $\ f\ $ measurable.  Without that assumption $\ Y_{n+1}\ $ would not necessarily be measurable—even if $\ Y_n\ $ and $\ X_n\ $ were—and therefore not even a random variable, let alone part of a Markov chain.